# Overriding delegate property in a UIScrollView subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, delegates, subclass

I have a scroll view subclass with a custom delegate that extends UIScrollViewDelegate. I'd like to name that property 'delegate' as well, in order to keep with Apple's patterns. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
@protocol ScrollViewSubclassDelegate <UIScrollViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
- (void)additionalDelegateMethod;
@end

@interface ScrollViewSubclass : UIScrollView
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ScrollViewSubclassDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

I also override the setDelegate method in the implementation, because I want to have that delegate be the delegate of a UITextField subview. For example:

```
@implementation ScrollViewSubclass

- (void)setDelegate:(id<ScrollViewSubclassDelegate>)delegate
{
    if (![_delegate isEqual:delegate]) {
        _delegate = delegate;
        self.myTextField.delegate = delegate;
    }
}

@end
```

However, when I do that, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIScrollView._delegate", referenced from:
      -[ScrollViewSubclass setDelegate:] in ScrollViewSubclass.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried adding `@synthesize delegate;` and `@dynamic delegate;`, as some  other SO posts have mentioned, but neither has worked.

Any advice on how to do this would be much appreciated.

PS obviously I could just name the delegate property something else, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this, but seems like it isn't good solution from design point of view

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<ScrollViewSubclassDelegate>)delegate
{
    if (![self.delegate isEqual:delegate]) {
        [super setDelegate:delegate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a private ivar of your superclass.  If you want the superclass to be able to still do all of it's own delegate logic then you should call `[super setDelegate:delegate]` in your subclass setter.